# How to include separate

Tags: c#, .net, git, visual-studio

So I have an ASP.NET MVC project at, let's say,

```
C:/Users/me/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/MyWebApp
```

and I have a git repo for that directory. *In that same repo* I want to include a project with a separate assembly that is a basic command-line program that scripts my database and puts them in a folder like `/DbScripts/GenerateDb.Sql` or something. If I create a new solution for this command-line program in VS and then do Add Existing Project, the issue is that the solution is not physically contained in `C:/Users/me/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/MyWebApp` so it is outside my repo.

Hopefully that makes sense. Any guidance on how I can do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Add the command line app as a new project to the existing solution and they should be both in the same repo.

Comment: why you create new solution? just create new project in the current solution.

Comment: @KarelTamayo will that make a separate .exe?

Comment: @DeadlyNicotine indeed! You'll create a new project, that's a new .exe in this case. Did you expect a different result?